# how to convert this slim to ERB?

Tags: ruby, autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, slim-lang

Am trying autocomplete in rails. since am noob in rails am not able to convert this slim code to erb so can anybody help me out!!!

first slim file

```
# app/views/books/index.html.slim
= form_tag books_path, class: "form-inline", method: :get do
.form-group
= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: "form-control"
'
= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary"
- if params[:query].present?
'
= link_to "clear", books_path
```

second slim file

```
 #app/views/layouts/application.html.slim
 = javascript_include_tag "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.9.3/ typeahead.min.js"
```

third slim file

```
# app/views/books/index.html.slim
= form_tag books_path, class: "form-inline", method: :get do
.input-group.input-group-lg
- if params[:query].present?
.input-group-btn
= link_to "clear", books_path, class: "btn btn-default"
= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: "form-control", id: "book_search", autocomplete: "off"
.input-group-btn
 = submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Comment: Try `slimrb -e index.html.slim > index.html.erb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

```
<%=form_tag books_path, class: "form-inline", method: :get do %>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: "form-control" %>    
  <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% if params[:query].present? %>    
    <%= link_to "clear", books_path %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Second:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.9.3/ typeahead.min.js" %>
```

Third:

```
<%= form_tag books_path, class: "form-inline", method: :get do %>
<div class="input-group input-group-lg" >
  <% if params[:query].present? %>
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <%= link_to "clear", books_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
 </div>
 <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: "form-control", id: "book_search", autocomplete: "off" %>
 <div class="input-group-btn">
   <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
 </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

You can always verify it here - http://html2slim.herokuapp.com/

Enjoy.

Comment: pay attention that no all block `do ... end` has final end!